# Passing a variable to Dockerfile and also using it in the Tag version?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Does anyone know how I can use some kind of variable in both the Dockerfile and also in the docker-compose file for tagging ?

I noticed there are ARGS here https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#args

So it appears I can send this through to the Dockerfile but how to use it in the docker-compose for tagging the version.

for example

```
  postrgres:
    image: myrepo/postgres:$$HERE NEED TO USE THE VARIABLE AS TAG$$

    build: ./postgres
```

I would like to receive the same value in both the Dockerfil and also use it in the TAG version.

Anybody know how to do this ?

Checked the docs but I couldn't find anything.

THanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not tried but I would imagine a configuration like that :

```
  postrgres:
    image: myrepo/postgres:${POSTGRES_VERSION}
    build: ./postgres
    args:
      - POSTGRES_VERSION
```

And with Dockerfile that starts like :

```
ARG POSTGRES_VERSION
FROM  myrepo/postgres:${POSTGRES_VERSION}
```

Then allow the docker compose template to know the value for `$POSTGRES_VERSION`.
Either add it in your shell as a `$POSTGRES_VERSION` env var:

```
export POSTGRES_VERSION=12.0
```

Or simply set the value in the `.env` file.

Comment: I have docker-compose version 3 and the only solution is to use `.env` file.